# jQuery dropdown not firing the delete button

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

In my small practice project, I have a dropdown with a delete button:

```
function getMessages() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Message/GetMessageMethod",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                var jsonData = $.parseJSON(data);
                var newHtml = "<table style='width: 100%;'class='table-hover'><tr><th>Message</th><th>Date Posted</th><th>Posted by</th></tr>";
                for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                    newHtml += "<tr><td>" + jsonData[i].message + "</td><td>" + jsonData[i].date + " - " + jsonData[i].time + "</td><td>" + jsonData[i].name + "</td><td><div class='btn-group'>"+
                    "<a class='btn dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#'> Actions " +
                        "<span class='caret'></span></a>" +
                        "<ul class='dropdown-menu' role='menu'>" +
                        "<li role='presentation'><input type='button' role='menuitem' value='Delete' class='btn btn-danger delMsg'/></li>" +
                        "</ul></div></td></tr>";
                }
                newHtml += "<table>";
                $('#txfMessage').html(newHtml);
            }
        });
    };
```

But my delete button is not firing when I click on it... I have a break point in firebug, but its not reaching it...

```
$('.delMsg').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Message/DeleteMessage",
                contenetType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    id: $('#txfMessage').val()
                }),
                success: function() {
                    getMessages();
                }
            });
        });
```

What could be I doing wrong, I've been busy with this since yesterday but couldn't find anything... Help please!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you try jQuery(document).on('click','.delMsg',function( instead of your ('.delMsg').on ?

Comment: wich jquery lib..version u have using .. ?

Comment: @Pierre Granger... Thanks, its firing now.. WoW!

Comment: @Ananti... I'm using jquery-2.1.0.js

Comment: It's the "new" syntax for .live with jQuey 1.7+. It allows to bind every new DOM element created after your first bind. See this page for more infos : https://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @Pierre Granger... Thank you once again, this is very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use jQuery event delegation, because you are attempting to attach an event to an element which does not yet exist in the DOM.

Change:

```
$('.delMsg').on('click', function () {
```

to:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delMsg', function () {
```

Check out [this link](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Since the delete button is created AFTER the AJAX call, your "on" method does not attach the event to it. You may use the [live](https://api.jquery.com/live/) method. It will account for elements created after the method is attached.

EDIT: By the way, this depends on the JQuery version. `live` still works. If you have to use `on`, use it correctly, like pointed out by Pierre Granger and Jamie Dunstan.

Comment: Depending on your version of jQuery it's preferable to use .on instead of live, but using this syntax :
jQuery(document).on('click','.delMsg',function(){}) ; https://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: .live() is deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. You should be using .on() as in the excellent comment by @PierreGranger.

Comment: @Stepanian... Since I'm using `jquery-2.1.0.js`, `live` will not work and i agree with using `on`

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like:

```
$('#txfMessage').html(newHtml);
$('.delMsg').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Message/DeleteMessage",
                contenetType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "json",
                cache: false,
                data: JSON.stringify({
                    id: $('#txfMessage').val()
                }),
                success: function() {
                    getMessages();
                }
            });
        });
```

i.e. bind each time you append new html elements, or use event delegation as in the other answers.